# How to include ONLY specific rows or columns from a CSV that is being pulled into an HTML table via PHP?

Tags: php, csv, import

I have a client who wants a table auto populated from a CSV file. The site is a Joomla site (v. 3.3.x) and I was using the Tabulizer component but what the client wants is a little too cherry-picking for Tabulizer's ability.

How can I cherry pick what columns and rows are pulled in from the CSV?

For example, let's say the CSV has 10 columns and 10 rows and I need a table that displays:

Row 2: Col 3 | Col 4 | Col 5 | Col 6 | Col 7 | Col 8 | Col 10

Row 3: Col 3 | Col 4 | Col 5 | Col 6 | Col 7 | Col 8 | Col 10

**Row 5:** Col 3 | Col 4 | Col 5 | Col 6 | Col 7 | **Col 9** | Col 10

Also, how can I force a search and replace? For example, if I wanted all empty cells to be relaced with "N/A" or all occurrences of "Blue Eyed Redheads" with just "Blue Eyes"?

Thanks in advance!

Cynthia

Comment: http://www.tabulizer.com/index.php/features

The list of features does mention data modification and data replacement.  I think you can pick something there.

Comment: I've already been back and forth w/ the developer. I can modify the data to some extent - like excluding specific rows. I can also exclude specific columns but that applies to ALL rows. I can't just remove a set of columns from one row and a different set of columns from another row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cherry Pick** - Add a filter

```
$filter = array(
  '2' => '3,4,5,6,7,8,10',
  '3' => '3,4,5,6,7,8,10',
  '5' => '3,4,5,6,7,9,10'
);

if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {

        $row = 1;

        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

          if(array_key_exists($row, $filter))
          {
            $columns = explode(",", $filter[$row]);                                                    

            for($i = 0; $i <= count($data); $i++)
            { 
              if(in_array($i, $columns))
              {
                echo $data[$i - 1] . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
              }
            }

            echo "<br />";
          }
            $row++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to take what you did and extrapolate it so that it is formatted as an HTML table: http://digitaldemo.net/table/table.php

Comment: Be careful with cases when csv data has special characters like comma, or backslash before ", see http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fgetcsv.php - but I hope your data is fine.